# Why can't I call this method via string?

Tags: c#, .net, reflection, method-invocation

Question from a Reflection newbie. I have a method in a Windows Form:

```
private void handleOrderCode()
{
  //...do stuff
}
```

Which I am trying to call in the following manner:

```
Type t = this.GetType();
MethodInfo mi = t.GetMethod("handleOrderCode");
if (mi != null) mi.Invoke(this, null);
```

I have confirmed that "this" is not null. The space where the string "handleOrderCode" has been hardcoded is to be replaced with a string variable when this works. However, at present "mi" is always null when it evaluates in the if statement in the final line.

So what am I doing wrong?

Comment: @NimsDotNet: Unless you call an instance method non-virtually in IL. It can be done :)

Comment: yeah, one of my Google searches on this before asking highlighted that there are some circumstances in which, weirdly, it can be, so I thought I'd double check. Belt and braces and all that.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You need to specify binding flags:

```
using System.Reflection;

t.GetMethod("handleOrderCode", BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.NonPublic)
```

---

Because overload without any flag means:

```
BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Static | BindingFlags.Instance
```

i.e. will not return any non-public (private, protected, etc) members.

Comment: you'd think that one of the many tuts on this that I Googled might mention that... but no. Thanks.

Answer (score 5):

The [parameterless overload of `Type.GetMethod`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8zz808e6.aspx) only looks for public methods:

> Searches for the public method with the specified name.

You need to specify an appropriate [`BindingFlags`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.bindingflags.aspx) value to [another overload](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/05eey4y9.aspx) instead:

```
MethodInfo method = t.GetMethod("handleOrderCode",
                                BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.NonPublic);
```

Note that you need to specify "instance" or "static" here (or both), not just "non-public". If you want to look for public methods as well, you have to include that too.

Another alternative is just to make your method public :)

(Additionally, I'd suggest renaming it to `HandleOrderCode` to be more conventional, idiomatic C#.)

Answer (score 4):

try:

```
Type t = this.GetType();
MethodInfo mi = t.GetMethod("handleOrderCode", 
   BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Instance);
if (mi != null) mi.Invoke(this, null);
```